# Modify apache httpd access log on the fly

Tags: apache, httpd.conf

I'm trying to replace some data in the apache httpd access log before it's written.
I've tried this

```
CustomLog "|/usr/bin/sed -E 's/pattern/replacement/g' | /usr/sbin/rotatelogs -l /var/log/httpd/access_log.%Y%m%d 86400" custom
```

which fails with

```
AH00106: piped log program '/usr/bin/sed -E 's/pattern/replacement/g' | /usr/sbin/rotatelogs -l /var/log/httpd/access_log.%Y%m%d 86400' failed unexpectedly
/usr/bin/sed: can't read |: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/sed: can't read 86400: No such file or directory
```

If I put the following in /usr/local/bin/sed-rotatelogs

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/bin/sed -E 's/pattern/replacement/g' | /usr/sbin/rotatelogs $@
```

and changes the CustomLog to

```
CustomLog "|/usr/local/bin/sed-rotatelogs -l /var/log/httpd/access_log.%Y%m%d 86400"
```

it works.

The buffer is quite large, which perhaps could be remedied by the -u option?

**I've got three questions:**

1. Is there a better way? E.g. an Apache module / filter?
2. Is the first solution possible?
3. How big is the performance penalty?

Comment: So you want to remove your traces from the log file of the system you broke into? ;-)

Comment: Actually I want to mask part of an ID used in query parameters, e.g. 0123456789 -> 012345xxxx. As stated I've got a working solution, but I wondered if there's a better way.